# How to get ride of JavaScript errors when using ng-repeat variable as a PHP function parameter?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am have a function `qsys::getFullUrl()` in PHP which resolves the full URL to images.

Inside the parameter, I need to include an angular variable.

Surprisingly, this actually works, and shows the image:

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in books | orderBy:'rank':true">
    <td style="border-top:none"><img style="width: 100px" src="<?= qsys::getFullUrl('customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png') ?>"/></td>
    <td style="border-top:none" >
        <div class="h4">{{book.title}}</div>
        <div><small>{{book.description}}</small></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, I also get Javascript errors:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/test/customImages/%7B%7Bbook.idcode%7D%7D.png"
```

How can I get rid of these JavaScript errors?

Comment: couldn't you just do `url_decode()` on the results?

Comment: JavaScript errors? I think those %7B = { so depends where they are encoded.  is your {{ }} template done client or server side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Angular, but in PHP I would probably do something like this:

```
<?= url_decode(qsys::getFullUrl('customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png')) ?>
```

That will then decode the values, but it will decode everything that that function returns, so you might want to only decode that, which you could do this:

```
$book_file = qsys::getFullUrl('customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png');
echo str_replace("%7B%7Bbook.idcode%7D%7D", "{{book.idcode}}", $book_file) ?>
```

You could even have your string replace do this to just replace `{` and `}`:

```
$find    = array("%7B","%7D");
$replace = array("{","}");
echo str_replace($find, $replace, qsys::getFullUrl('customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png')) ?>
```

Using either of these methods should get you a url that finalizes to the browser like this:

```
 http://localhost/test/customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png"
```

Angular should then be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with `ng-src`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in books| orderBy:'rank':true">
    <td style="border-top:none"><img style="width: 100px" ng-src="{{absolutePath}}customImages/{{book.idcode}}.png"/></td>
    <td style="border-top:none" >
        <div class="h4">{{book.title}}</div>
        <div><small>{{book.description}}</small></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and by putting the fullUrl in the module:

`$scope.absolutePath = '<?= qsys::getFullUrl() ?>';`